# Avoid rounding error when manually parsing double

Tags: parsing, double, rounding-error

I wanted to implement a simple parser for double values (just for fun). However, I noticed that when handling the decimal shift, I get rounding errors when multiplying the value with powers of 10.

I'm wondering how `double.Parse` ensures that the result value is as close to the string value as possible?

Just an example:
When parsing 0.0124 (=124*0.0001), I get 0.012400000000000001. However, `double.Parse` displays 0.0124 as expected.

Comment: I hope you realize that in both cases it isn't equal to 0.0124, but it's a good question to understand A. what is the "real" value parsed by `double.Parse` and B. how does that work

Comment: Sure. The double value is stored in a binary format. So there is no exact representation for many decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems quite simple:
Just don't multiply by values smaller than 1 (e.g. 0.0001 in the above example) but divide by 1/x (10000 in the above example).

I think the reason is simply that integer values have an exact representation (up to 2^53), so there is no rounding error in the quotient (as there was in the factor < 1).